# Get positive numbers out of object where value is true

Tags: javascript

How can i parse this object?

```
$scope.selectedCountries = {2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: true, 7: true, 8: true, 9: true, 10: false, 11: true, 13: true, 14: true, 15: true, 17: true, 18: false, 19: true, 20: false, 21: true, 22: false, 23: true, 24: false, 25: false, 26: false};
```

I have already tried forEach, of array position as [1] or [0], etc...

I want to fetch all numbers where there value is true and store it as array value in variable

example:

```
var ids = [2,3,4,5,7,8,9,11,13,14,15,17,18,21,23]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get property names using Object.keys and filter it like this:

```
var selectedCountries = {2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: true, 7: true, 8: true, 9: true, 10: false, 11: true, 13: true, 14: true, 15: true, 17: true, 18: false, 19: true, 20: false, 21: true, 22: false, 23: true, 24: false, 25: false, 26: false};

var ids = Object.keys(selectedCountries).filter(function(key) {
    return selectedCountries[key];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Object.keys(selectedCountries)` to get an array of the keys in your object and then loop through that new array:

```
$scope.ids = []; //initialise ids as an array
$scope.selectedCountries = {2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: true, 7: true, 8: true, 9: true, 10: false, 11: true, 13: true, 14: true, 15: true, 17: true, 18: false, 19: true, 20: false, 21: true, 22: false, 23: true, 24: false, 25: false, 26: false};
var keys = Object.keys($scope.selectedCountries);//get a list of all keys in selectedCountries

keys.forEach(function(k) { //loop through all keys 
    if ($scope.selectedCountries[k]) { //if the value for that key in selectedCountries is true
        $scope.ids.push(k); //push it to ids
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would get desired result with `for` loop below:

```
var $scope = {'selectedCountries': {2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: true, 7: true, 8: true, 9: true, 10: false, 11: true, 13: true, 14: true, 15: true, 17: true, 18: false, 19: true, 20: false, 21: true, 22: false, 23: true, 24: false, 25: false, 26: false}};

var results = [];
for (key in $scope.selectedCountries){
    if ($scope.selectedCountries[key]) {
      results.push(parseInt(key));
}}
console.log(results)
```

**Good Luck!**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate keys of an object, use `for in` expression. As for your case:

```
var selectedCountries = {2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: true, 7: true, 8: true, 9: true, 10: false, 11: true, 13: true, 14: true, 15: true, 17: true, 18: false, 19: true, 20: false, 21: true, 22: false, 23: true, 24: false, 25: false, 26: false};  
var ids = [];
for(key in selectedCountries) {
    if (selectedCountries[key]) {
        ids.push(+key)
    } 
}
console.log(ids);
```

And you will get the array. Note this `arr.push(+key)`, `+` will do the same job as `Number()`.